# How to read 5 lines from text file then save the remaining lines back to this same file

Tags: php

I have a text file with 200 lines like the following:

```
google  
yahoo  
bing  
msn  
soso  
baidu
```

I want to read that text file and and get first 5 lines to `array` and save all remaining lines back to same text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple. You can exactly implement like the following code.

```
<?php

    $lines = file('text.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $five_line_array = array_splice($lines, 0, 5);

    $data = implode("\n", array_values($lines));

    $file = fopen('text.txt', "w+");
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);

    print_r($five_line_array); // output as Array ( [0] => google [1] => yahoo [2] => bing [3] => msn [4] => soso )
```

Comment: it worked, thanks the only issue in this code is single quote on line break '\n' it should be double quote "\n" then it will work. Thanks again.

Comment: @HarshSharma. Yeah, you're right. I did instantly write out the code in answer textbox without testing. Sorry, my false. I edited the answer. Glad that I could help you.